# How to get started on Infopath 2007 and Wokflow in MOSS 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infopath-forms-services

I am kind of new to SharePoint and have so far mostly worked with WebPart development. After two week or so i will have to work on an assignment where i need to know InfoPath and workflow

can some one point me to some articles or help to get me started on that ? Also ,It would be good to know which topics I should cover while i am on the learning path ?

thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Design InfoPath Workflow Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms548723.aspx)

> There are several basic steps to
>   designing a Microsoft InfoPath 2010
>   form for use with a Microsoft
>   SharePoint Server 2010 workflow

[Introduction to using workflows with InfoPath forms](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/introduction-to-using-workflows-with-infopath-forms-HA010204143.aspx)

> What are workflows? Ways to use
>   workflows with InfoPath forms;
>   Workflows that are included in
>   SharePoint sites; Support for custom
>   workflows in SharePoint

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention that i will be working on Infotpath 2007 in MOSS 2007..

Comment: But thanks for 2010 link which lead me to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296354(office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

When I started workflow development, the book 'Workflow in the 2007 Microsoft Office System (Apress)' was a great help. Since you have two weeks left, reading that book might help you a lot.

It covers SharePoint Designer workflows, workflows developed in Visual Studio (2005 but 2008 is not that different) and workflows with custom initiation/assocation forms.